# How to automatically resize uploaded photo in PHP?

Tags: php, resize, kohana

How to auto resize the image uploaded to this foder: 'assets/media/':

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

class Uploader_Controller extends Controller_Core {

public function bulkUpload() {
    Kohana::log('debug', 'Start to upload');
    $files = Validation::factory($_FILES)
                    ->add_rules('picture', 'upload::valid', 'upload::required', 'upload::type[gif,jpg,png,jpeg]', 'upload::size[10M]');
    Kohana::log('debug', 'Start to validate');
    if ($files->validate()) {
        Kohana::log('debug', 'validate passed');

        $filename = upload::save('picture');
        $thumbSize = Kohana::config('upload.thumb_size');

        Image::factory($filename)
                ->resize($thumbSize[0], $thumbSize[1], Image::WIDTH)
                ->save(DOCROOT . 'assets/media/thumbs/' . basename($filename));

        $partName = explode('/', $filename);
        $picture = $partName[count($partName) - 1];
        $data['name'] = '';
        $data['picture'] = $picture;
        $data['category_id'] = $this->input->post('category_id', 0);
        $data['description'] = '';
        ;
        $data['user_id'] = $this->input->post('user_id', 0);
        $pictureModel = new Picture_Model();
        try {
            $photo = $pictureModel->savePicture($data);
            echo url::site('assets/media/' . $picture);
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }
}
}
```

i have add this line but still not working:

`$filename->resizeToWidth(300);`

Comment: I don't see a question here. What did you try, what did not work for you? Show us some work and effort and people will be very happy to help.

Comment: Use PHP GD library. There is an example here: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Comment: Can anyone help me? i don't have a big knowledge on Php. I have tried to add this line to the script, but it is not working:

$filename->resizeToWidth(150);

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the Kohana image and upload library properly. The docs have some examples on how to use the Kohana image upload and resize library:

- [Upload and resize](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/image/examples/upload)
- [Cropping Profile Images](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/image/examples/crop)
- [Docs on how to use the image library](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/image/using)

You can resize and save an image with to following code:

```
Image::factory($filename)
    ->resize(300, NULL, Image::AUTO)
    ->save($your_save_path);
```